Unknown namespace issues after referencing project in 'main' project C#
I'm using VS Code for my project (docGenerator). I added another project as a reference to it, named common. The common project is already referenced in several other existing projects, and everything works fine in those cases. However, common is targeting .NET 5, while the main projects, including docGenerator, are targeting .NET 8.
After adding common to docGenerator, I started getting errors for all the packages referenced in common.
For instance, I'm seeing errors for using Amazon.Lambda; even though the common project works fine wherever it's referenced elsewhere.
I've tried reinstalling the packages, clearing the NuGet cache, and restoring the packages, but none of these steps have resolved the issue.
using Amazon.Lambda;
using Amazon.Lambda.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Common.AWS
{
    public class AWSLambdaService
    {
        private readonly IAmazonLambda _lambdaClient;

        public AWSLambdaService(IAmazonLambda lambdaClient)
        {
            _lambdaClient = lambdaClient;
        }

        //...
    }
}

The error I get:

The type or namespace name 'Lambda' does not exist in the namespace 'Amazon' (are you missing an assembly reference?) CS0234


Your package reference is in the Common.csproj, right? and the project reference to Common is in docGenerator.csproj? Common, being NET5 will need to use the net standard 2.0 version of the library, and if you reference the package from docGenerator you'll be getting the net6.0 version. Do you see any other compiler warnings, they should help you find the problem. If you're still stuck, start examining the output folders and the nuget package folder.

@iakobski no problem in any other projects . they're all .net 8 the same as this one , and has Common project as reference

So where's the package reference? And what's in the output folder?
